# File Decryption not working in Node when encrypted from php

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

**It's solved finally, you can see my answers below**
File Decryption not working in Node when encrypted from php
PHP Code to Encrypt

```
<?php

$key = "f9036c20bdb656106fd176d260878c63";
$iv = "7152201381f54b46";




exec('openssl enc -aes-256-cbc   -K '.$key.' -iv '.$iv.' -in a.txt -out b.txt');



exec('openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc  -K '.$key.' -iv '.$iv.' -in b.txt -out outr.txt');
?>
```

Decryption works fine in PHP

JS code for Decryption both the below approach is not working

```
var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
var key ="f9036c20bdb656106fd176d260878c63";

var iv1 = "7152201381f54b46";


var text = require('fs').readFileSync('../b.txt');

var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(text,key,{iv:iv1, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });

console.log(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(bytes));
require('fs').writeFile('../out.txt', CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(bytes), function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
    });
```

Also tried with crypto no luck

```
    const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');

var secret = "f9036c20bdb656106fd176d260878c63";
const buf_secret = Buffer.from(secret);

var iv = "7152201381f54b46";
const buf_iv = Buffer.from(iv);


const decipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', buf_secret, buf_iv);
decipher.setAutoPadding(true);
fs.readFile('../b.txt', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    const buf_data = Buffer.from(data);
    console.log(buf_data);
    let decrypted = decipher.update(buf_data, 'utf8');
    decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
    console.log(decrypted);

});
```

I am sure some padding issue is there, can someone point out what error its having?

Comment: Your key is only 128 bits and your IV is 64 which are both wrong. `openssl enc -K -iv` pads with zeros; I don't know what either JS does. Also on the second one it looks like you're claiming your ciphertext is base64 when it isn't, although I would expect this to throw some error, and that the encryption wasn't padded, which will cause your output to contain added garbage which may not be visible depending how you look.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I got it fixed, The problem is PHP openssl accepts key and iv as hex. For openssl256 key length should be 64 and iv length should be 32, but in PHP key length was 32 and iv length was 16 which is for openssl128, so PHP is adding trailing zeros. In JS after adding trailing zeros and considering it as hex its working fine.

Comment: To be exact PHP just passes the (hex) strings to `openssl`; it is `openssl` that converts from hex, finds them too short and pads. But same result.

Answer (score 1):

It's solved. The problem is PHP openssl accepts key and iv as hex. For openssl256 key length should be 64 and iv length should be 32, but in PHP key length was 32 and iv length was 16 which is for openssl128, so PHP is adding trailing zeros. In JS after adding trailing zeros and considering it as hex its working fine.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');
const key_size = 64;
const iv_size = 32;

var secret = "f9036c20bdb656106fd176d260878c63";
secret = pad(secret,key_size,"0"); //pad with trailing zeros

const buf_secret = Buffer.from(secret,'hex');

var iv = "7152201381f54b46";
iv = pad(iv,iv_size,"0");//pad with trailing zeros

const buf_iv = Buffer.from(iv,'hex');



const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', buf_secret, buf_iv);
decipher.setAutoPadding(true);

const input = fs.createReadStream('../b.txt');
const output = fs.createWriteStream('../decrypted.txt');

input.pipe(decipher).pipe(output);

//content if you want instead of direct writing
//fs.readFile('../b.txt', function (err, data) {
//    if (err) {
//        return console.log(err);
//    }
//    const buf_data = Buffer.from(data);
//    console.log(buf_data);
//    let decrypted = decipher.update(buf_data, 'utf8');
//    decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
//    console.log(decrypted);
//
//});

//for padding trailing zeros
function pad(value, width, padchar) {

    while (value.length < width) {
        value += padchar;
    }
    return value;
}
```